# What is ReDim myarray(True to True) in VBA?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, ms-access, migration

I'm doing a project that converts code written in VBA to C# ASP.NET.

I'm stuck at the following statement:

```vb
Dim mtyRESULT() As TYP_RESULT

ReDim mtyRESULT(True To True) '<=== This statement
```

So, what is `ReDim myarray(True to True)`? What is its purpose? And what is the equivalent of that statement in C#?

Comment: What `TYP_RESULT` is?

Comment: @FaneDuru TYP_RESULT is just a user-defined data type.

Comment: I was supposing that, but how the variable, declared in this way, is used in the code you try translating?

Answer (score 3):

[ReDim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) statement defined new array with one element:

[image]

TRUE in VBA is -1, so dimension of your array mtyRESULT will be from -1 to -1

Comment: This does not really answer the question about the purpose of using `True to True`. If someone wanted an array from -1 to -1, why not ReDim it as `(-1 to -1)`?

Comment: @horst What is the purpose? Just show off. What is the purpose of a single element array? Blow up the basics of VBA programming?

Comment: @JohnSUN thanks for the answer, but how about the purpose of this statement ? And how we migrate this code into C# ?

Comment: @QuanTn From two lines of code it is impossible to guess what purpose the author of the code pursued to create an "array of one element" - you need to see how he was going to use it. Now it looks just silly. To translate stupidity from one language to another is to double the stupidity. When translating into C#, one should comprehend the algorithm and implement it by means of language, and not translate "word for word".  I answered the question from the title, for two additional questions I have no answers.